# Android Context Practices

Tags: android, integration-testing, android-context

I have a question, if I have a class that sends data from android device to a server and gets response.

Why would I want to have only one constructor for this class that takes Context context as a parameter?

```
Public class SendReceive
{
   public SendReceive(Context context)
   {//code here}
}
```

I do not have deep understanding of Context, as far as I understand, it represents environment data.

Do I necessarily need to pass Context as a parameter for such class's constructor?

Comment: `Do I necessarily need to pass Context as a parameter for such class's constructor?` Do you need it? if yes then add it.

Comment: I am not the one who programmed it, I am questioning why the developer had to use it, he even did not give us the option to use this class without using Context,
Should I be able to send data and receive response without using it?

Comment: Probably the last developer who made that code forgot to remove that. If it is not used then having it in the constructor is not necessary.

Comment: You are genius man, I tracked the usage of this parameter and I reached a point where I could find that it is not used at all!

Comment: That was just my guess, anyway If I where you I will definitely re-implement that logic and commit that constructor because it's not good to maintain an unused code and might just cause some confusion with your fellow developers. Also `Version control` is your friend.

Comment: will raise this issue, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start reading about context from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)

> Context is Interface to global information about an application environment. This is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android system. It allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc

if you have any method (toasts,intents..etc) which uses context then pass context in constructor else just use empty constructor

```
public SendReceive()
 {
//code here
 }
```

if you are in activity then only you can use `getApplicationContext()`  else use  `context.getApplicationContext()` in fragments use `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`

Comment: An `Activity` is a `Context`, though, so you should rarely need `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: I need to test the send receive functionality in a test class, none of the getApplicationContext() usages worked for me

Comment: @YahyaHHussein You should post a new question about obtaining a context during tests.